# How to make HTML auth form and JSON Web Tokens communicate together in Ionic/Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, jwt

I'm working on an Ionic application.
On the one hand I have an auth basic form in which people fill in their username and password. On the other hand I'd like to implement authentification with JSON Web Tokens and Node JS.
The workflow would be this one : as soon as a user fills in his credentials, they will be sent with a POST request. If these credentials are correct, the user can access to the application and gets an access token as a response.

The thing is that I'm a little bit lost with all that concepts. I built a form and sent informations with a POST request. I managed to create some APIs with Node JS and that's ok. I see how to build a authentified webservice too (e.g : https://github.com/jkasun/stack-abuse-express-jwt/blob/master/auth.js).
But I concretely don't understand the links between the html form and the authorisation check part..
To be clearer, how is it possible to make the html part and the Node JS scripts communicate together ?

Before posting that question I made many researches and found many stuff on building an authentified API. But there was very few advice on how to make it communicate with the client part (I mean the form), which is what I have to do.
If anyone has any ressources (document, Github examples..) on that, I'll greatly appreciate. But I would be very happy too if someone try to make me understand these concepts. I guess I have to improve my knowledge on all that so that I could test some POCs.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Angular post method or jwt auth .  What is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT General flow:

1- Authenticate using a strategy (You done it)

2- Deliver an accessToken along with response (You done it)

3- The client MUST store this accessToken (LocalStorage is the best place, not cookies: They are vulnerable to csrf attacks)

4- On every request you are going to make to a protected area (where user is supposed to be authenticated and authorized), make sure to send you accessToken along with it, you can put it on Authorization header, a custom header, directly in body of the request... Basicaly just make sure to send it properly.

5- On the server receiving client requests, you NEED to verify that token (You verify it by checking the signature of the accessToken).

6- If he is authorized, great, if not, send back an HTTP Unauthorized Error.

Here is my implementation using an accessToken on a header + passportjs-jwt:

**Client code**

To store token:

```
localStorage.setItem('accessToken', myAccessToken);
```

To send it:

```
const myAccessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

{
  headers: {'Authorization', `Bearer ${myAccessToken}`}
}
```

**Server code**

1- Configure passport

```
passport.use('jwt', new JwtStrategy({
  jwtFromRequest: jwtPassport.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: myAccessTokenSecret,
  passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, payload, done: (err?, user?) => void): void {
User
  .findOne({where: {id: req.params.id}})
  .then((user: User) => {

    if (!user) {
      return done(new Error(`No user found with id: ${req.params.id}`), null);
    }

    return done(null, user);
  })
  .catch((e: Error) => done(e, null));
}));
```

Pay attention to callback: If your callback is called, it means that passport has successfuly verified the token (It is valid). In my example, i get the user details in database and this is the user that will be returned and put in req.user object passed to my controller below:

2- Finally, the controller route (protected area):

```
.get('/users/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt'), (req, res, next) => {
  // do stuff in protected area.
}
```

And that's it. If you want more security, check refreshTokens implementation.

I used passport because i found it relevant in my case, but you can write your own handler, by using jsonwebtoken and just calling its "verify" function.

You can find documentation of passport jwt strategy here => http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/

Comment: Great Sir, thank you very much for havink taken time to answer. I understand what you're saying and it does really help. But it remains one thing I don't get.. When you have stuff like that in your form  `<ion-input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>`, how do you send that to a POST request that communicates after with Node JS and JWT ?

Comment: And generally speaking, how the Node JS and JWT part can check if the POST request  sent contains valid credentials ?

Comment: After some hours of testing,I finally managed to do it, thanks again @millenion !! In my login method I stored the token with `localStorage.setItem`. Then I put it in my headers options. The headers options are called in the POST request. Therefore I'm authorized to send data.